# PHP SimpleXML replaceChild() Error: "Call to undefined method[...]"

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am running PHP5 on a Linux Apache Server

I am trying to use XML in my website as a simple database.

I need to raise an integer  (the content of a node) by one, and save the file.

The Error Message is : **Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::replaceChild()**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
$z = $_GET['z'];        
$dom = simplexml_load_file("questions.xml");
if ($dom->question['id'] == $x) {
    $poll = $dom->question->poll;
    if ($z == 0) {
        $yes = $poll->yes;
        $upper = $yes + 1;
        $yes->replaceChild($yes, $upper);
    } elseif ($z == 1) {
        $no = $poll->no;
        $lower = $no + 1;
        $no->replaceChild($no, $lower);
    }
}
?>
```

questions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<questions>
    <question id="does-god-exist">
    <poll>
        <yes>0</yes>
        <no>0</no>
    </poll>
    </question>
</questions>
```

Comment: You can use `DOMDocument::load() : Load XML from a file` and then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceChild` is a method of the `DOMNode` class, not `simpleXML`. `SimpleXML` does not provide any method to replace or remove a child, so you need to use [dom_import_simplexml](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) and then you can use the function `replaceChild` in your converted DOM object.

Comment: what would be a solution then? is there an alternative for the simpleXML library?

Comment: yes, you can convert your simpleXML object to a DOM object using dom_import_simplexml

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
$yes = $poll->yes;
$upper = $yes + 1;
$yes->replaceChild($yes, $upper);
```

... where `$yes` is a [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object and such class does not have any `replaceChild()` method. I guess you want something like this instead:

```
$poll->yes++;
```